# Installing Windows 7 hangs after initial loading phase

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64 bit on a machine with a X7DAL-E motherboard, but it stops after the initial loading phase, as soon as the mouse pointer appears on a colored background.

The computer is not frozen: I can move the pointer, but nothing else happens.

Comment: what is this x7dal-e in the question title?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek A [motherboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5000X/X7DAL-E.cfm) it seems.

Comment: Have you cleared your CMOS? If not, then do that

Comment: no I don't. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, I don't know why, but waiting ~30 min the installation go on. I don't know if the CMOS reset helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the BIOS (CMOS) in the first 10 seconds or so after you power on your PC, normally by pressing **Del** or an **F key**. It may briefly display a message on the screen saying...

> Press Del to enter setup

...so do as it says. Check the manual that came with the Motherboard or look for a manual online.

Try resetting all the options to their defaults as Sandeep suggested above.

Some SATA drive modes need you to install drivers during the Windows installation process. Again, check with the manufacturers or your Motherboard and Hard Disk. You could change the SATA hard disk mode in the BIOS to standard ATA.

If you try the install again, do a full format of the drive when given the option and try again.

UPDATE: Your motherboard manufacturers website:
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5000X/X7DAL-E.cfm
Looks like you have a Pheonix BIOS so it should be Del you need to press. You can also download drivers and an update for your BIOS from here.

Comment: win7, in theory shoyuld have full sata support

Comment: Resetting the CMOS didn't help, and drivers are not an option: the installer halts before prompting *anything*.

Comment: Then I would try another DVD media or another DVD drive. Can you update the BIOS? Maybe install XP quickly or use a Preinstallation Environment like BartPE to run the update? Did changing the SATA mode not help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than 2GB of RAM installed? If you are using an older install disk (pre SP1) it can hang on install with more than 2 gigs.

Comment: This is definitely worth a try. If you have two sticks of RAM just try it with one in, and if that still doesn't work, try the other. Could be a faulty stick of ram.

Comment: I agree it could also be a bad stick. One at a time is a great idea.